# Has California implemented its "rocket tax" yet?

Tags: launch, united-states, government, business, space-taxes

Here are some questions from 2017:

- [California's rocket tax "by the mile", how would that work exactly?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21445/12102)
- [What expenses and risks might the state of California incur that might partially justify a new "rocket tax"?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21453/12102)

and their answers suggest that this was seriously considered several years ago.

Is it known if this is still being considered or if progress has been made towards its implementation?

Comment: In case anyone else was wondering, bumping is ok. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4397/purposeful-question-bumping-abuse-or-feature

Comment: @OrganicMarble ya I figure if Community♦ can "[Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)" it's okay if we do it once in a while ourselves, somewhat less randomly, for the purpose of attracting answers. Since I have a larger-than-average question base, everything I do appears magnified.